# PHP ftp_get causing warning and not downloading file

Tags: php, ftp

I've got a fairly simple cron job that pulls down some files from an FTP server - none of the files are particularly large, but I'm constantly getting the following:

```
Connected to voip.colefabrics.com, for user colefabrics\absolute

Warning: ftp_get(): Opening BINARY mode data connection. in /home/www/colefabrics.com/httpdocs/libs/classes/class.ftpObj.php on line 56
There was a problem while downloading website/items.csv

Attempt 2:

Connected to voip.colefabrics.com, for user colefabrics\absolute

Warning: ftp_get(): Opening BINARY mode data connection. in /home/www/colefabrics.com/httpdocs/libs/classes/class.ftpObj.php on line 56
There was a problem while downloading website/items.csv

...snip...
```

I've been through all the other posts relating to this, tried to enforce passive mode, increased the timeout, but nothing is working.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, and what I can do to try and resolve it?

To confirm, it's working fine via a 'normal' FTP client, it's only via PHP that I have a problem.

Comment: BINARY mode might be forced by FTP server. If that would be the case there is nothing you could do to force ASCII.

Comment: Hi @edvinas.me - it's not the Binary mode that's the problem - if I change it to ASCII mode (which I can do), then I get the same error, just with 'ASCII' instead of 'BINARY' in the error string.

The problem is that is shouldn't be doing that at all - it should be downloading the file!